# How to reorder DataFrame row sequences

Tags: python, pandas

I had defined a dataset :

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(xx))
```

then,I filtered some data based on gender.

```
df=df[df["sex"]=="1"]
```

then I should traverse all data.

```
row,col=df.shape
for i in range(row):
    print(df["name"][i])  # error
```

I debug the code,I found " df " row index is old index,Because many non-conforming data are deleted.for example df["sex"][1]==1 is delete,so The cycle will except.

How to reorder DataFrame row sequences
thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't *ever* use this construction:

```
for i in range(nrows):
    do_stuff(df[column][i])
```

It is inefficient. You almost *never* want to use a for-loop over a data-frame, but if you must, use `pd.Dataframe.itertuples`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5]})
>>> for row in df.itertuples():
...     print("the index", row.Index)
...     print("sum of row", row.a + row.b)
...
the index 0
sum of row 4
the index 1
sum of row 6
the index 2
sum of row 8
```

Note, it now doesn't matter if the index changes:

```
>>> df = df.iloc[[2,0,1]]
>>> df
   a  b
2  3  5
0  1  3
1  2  4
>>> for row in df.itertuples():
...     print("the index", row.Index)
...     print("sum of row", row.a + row.b)
...
the index 2
sum of row 8
the index 0
sum of row 4
the index 1
sum of row 6
```

Finally, you could have always just reset your index, suppose:

```
>>> df.drop(0, axis=0, inplace=True)
>>> df
   a  b
2  3  5
1  2  4
```

Now, just use:

```
>>> df.reset_index()
   index  a  b
0      2  3  5
1      1  2  4
```

And use the `drop` parameter to not include the old index as a column:

```
>>> df.reset_index(drop=True)
   a  b
0  3  5
1  2  4
```